# Apply form validation for template driven forms in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been trying to add functionality to my template-driven form, that
would check if passwords are equal using [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation), however
it seems that after applying validator directive to my form, the validation does not even fire.
My code:

**register.component.ts**

```
export const matchingPasswordValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const password = control.get('password');
  const confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassword');

  return password.value === confirmPassword.value ? { passwordMatch: true } : null;
};

@Directive({
  selector: '[matchingPassword]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MatchingPasswordValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class MatchingPasswordValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    return matchingPasswordValidator(control);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  registerPost: RegisterPost = new RegisterPost();
```

**register.component.html**

```
<form #registerForm="ngForm" matchingPassword>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="registerPost.email" name="email" #email="ngModel" email required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.errors?.email">
      Enter a valid email address
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
    <input type="password" matInput [(ngModel)]="registerPost.password" name="password" #password="ngModel"
      required>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Powtórz hasło</mat-label>
    <input type="password" matInput [(ngModel)]="registerPost.confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword"
      #confirmPassword="ngModel" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.errors?.passwordMatch">
      Password does not match.
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button type="submit" mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="!registerForm.valid || register()"
    [loading]="registerClicked">
    Register
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz?

Comment: Hey Andrei! Sure, I did that:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zlmyzr

Comment: I think you forgot to add `MatchingPasswordValidatorDirective` to the `declarations` array. And now I'm getting this warning: `The Angular Material version (10.1.3) does not match the Angular CDK version (9.2.4).
Please ensure the versions of these two packages exactly match.`. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-52vk6y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)